# Rotate relative to set point in a specified direction in a 3D space

Tags: mathematics, rotation, lua

I know there's a geometry formula to calculate the next point in rotation relative to another point in 2D but I'm working in 3D and I want to calculate the next position in specified direction as well. Think Spiderman or the Bloodstalkers from ARK. I'm working in a game engine that uses the basic {x = 1, y = 2, z = 1} for vectors. I'm pretty bad at math so I honestly can't figure this out myself.

Comment: Can you clarify what rotation you want to perform? What point, needs to rotate around what axis, around what pivot, by what angle?

Comment: Are you asking how to make something "swing" (move in a circular path) around some anchor point in 3D, in a given "swing plane"? If so, it would help if you added the 2D formula you're using to your question, I think it can be converted to its 3D analogue in a relatively straightforward way, provided that you can find two perpendicular unit vectors that would define the swing plane.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, game engines and math go hand in hand so understanding the underlying theory should be high in your priority list. I will try to explain this at a high level, based on what I understood and will try to elaborate later when I get the time. I will also put in bold terms you should look at.

Taking the spiderman swinging example, this means you have 2 points, namely the *building corner* the spiderweb is attached to and *spiderman* himself. These 2 points will give you a vector which we will name `spiderwebVector`. There is also a second vector which is what you refer to as *specified direction*. I'm assuming you know which direction that is (the direction spiderman is going). Let's name that vector `swingdirectionVector`.

Your steps should be the following:

1. Execute a **cross product** between the 2 vectors. This will give you a 3rd vector which will be the **axis of rotation** (the vector around which you are rotating).
2. Execute a second **cross product** between the `spiderwebVector` and the `axisVector`. This will give you another vector. (note: the new vector will probably have the same or inverse direction as the `swingdirectionVector`).
3. **Normalize** the 2 new vectors and the `spiderwebVector`. These new **unit vectors** now form a new **basis**. Essentially they are a new set of \$x',y',z'\$ basis vectors but their coordinates are expressed in **standard basis** \$x,y,z\$ values. Assume \$z\$ is the up vector.
4. Any rotation of angle \$θ\$ around an up axis (in our case either \$z\$ or \$z'\$) is defined by the following **rotation transformation matrix**
   $$R=\begin{pmatrix}
   \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
   \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}.$$
5. Because the rotation is around \$z'\$ (remember, the new **basis**) this transformation will rotate the points by \$θ\$ assuming they are expressed in the new **basis** coordinates, which I assume is not your case since everything is expressed in the **standard basis** \${x,y,z}\$.
6. In order to create the transformation that will rotate all the points expressed in **standard basis** coordinates, we execute a **change of basis** transformation first. This is another 3x3 matrix. Each **column** of that matrix represents \$x',y'\$ or \$z'\$ expressed in the **standard basis**. For example if \$x'=(0.57,0.57,0.57)\$ then the *first column* will be
   $$\begin{pmatrix}
   0.57 \\
   0.57 \\
   0.57
   \end{pmatrix}.$$
   We now have a change of basis matrix
   $$C=\begin{pmatrix}
   a & d & g \\
   b & e & h \\
   c & f & i
   \end{pmatrix}.$$
7. Finally, to execute the whole rotation, we sandwich the \$R\$ rotation matrix with the change of basis matrix and its **matrix inverse**
   $$
   U=CRC^{-1}
   $$
   It is important to note that the **inverse** comes on the right. The reason for this is a little more complicated but if you understand the change of basis concept it makes sense. More info can be found [here](http://www.michaelkeutel.de/blog/rotation-matrices-vector-basis/).
8. You take the \$U\$ **transformation matrix** and you multiply it with the vector that needs to rotate, in this case the `spiderwebVector`. Note that the vector must come from the **right-multiplication** `U * spiderwebVector`. This will give you a new vector that points to the new location spiderman ends up at after a rotation of angle \$θ\$.

I believe this is the gist of it, however I'm also new at this and any input/edits/**corrections** from more experienced members is very welcome.